# Android Studio 2.0 not been able to build project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I've updated android studio 1.5.1 to 2.0 in stable channel. Since then my project is not getting build.

Following is my gradle plugin :

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'`

Using gradle distribution as

`gradle/gradle-2.10`

Gradle console is stop at `:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug` after running for 2 hours. Please suggest what i'm doing wrong which failt these build.

*app.gradle*

```
            apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mobcast.sbilife"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidEasingFunctions-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidViewAnimations-1.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/recyclerview-animators-1.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/stetho-1.1.1-fatjar.jar')
    compile files('libs/stetho-okhttp-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/systembartint-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

*project.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

After waiting for couple of hours it throwswith following error :

`Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
>   `

Comment: post your gradle (both)

Comment: @Blackbelt. Hey! posted gradle file. Could you please guide me where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `com.google.android.gms:play-services` use one

Comment: add `multiDexEnabled true` & `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` then `clean-rebuild-sync`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I don't think so that will resolve my problem. I don't want to use extra play services utilities other then gcm.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : It was working fine since 1.5.1. Tried to added multiDex still it goes into infinite loop.

Comment: i assume you are using one of `old` jar file (version old)

Comment: comment `compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : Android Studio just went into meditation. Need to uninstall . Back to 1.5.1. No Hope to use Instant Run :/

Comment: Failed builds is expected when Google releases a new version of Android. Expect to spend countless hours tracking down your bug. Gradle sucks and should be killed off. Google expects devs to act as testers even when the new release is suppose to be "stable". lol

Comment: Yeah totally agreed with you @AndroidDev . I started using AS after they release 1.0 Even today I prefer Eclipse over AS. Just because they don't support multiDex, I sadly need to migrate to AS.